# Consulta Banco de Dados com um Array no hibernate

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

Tenho um método que recebe como parâmetro um array de valores(id) e preciso fazer uma consulta no banco de dados para retornar apenas as linhas de uma coluna com esses valores(id)
Tenho esse metodo:

```
public List<Lotacao> localizarPorId(long[] id){
    try {

        String sql = "select l from Lotacao l where l.id in :id";
        TypedQuery<Lotacao> q = em.createQuery(sql, Lotacao.class);

        for( int i = 0; i < id.length; i++) {
                q.setParameter("id", id[i]);
            }
        return q.getResultList();

        }catch(NoResultException e) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }
```

Porém ele só retorna do banco de dados a linha que corresponde ao valor do ultimo índice do Array. Alguém sabe como faz para ele retornar todas as linhas do BD correspondentes nos valores do Array?

Answer (score 1):

Você adapta ao seu, :D

```
List<Lotacao> logins = em.createQuery("select l from Lotacao l where l.id in :ids")
        .setParameter("ids",Arrays.asList(new Long(1000100), new Long(1000110)))
        .getResultList();
```